# What can be done to improve IE8 performance for large sets of data?

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a page which displays ~300 pages worth of tabular data.  Firefox, Chrome, Safari all work fine but IE 7, 8, and 8 Compatibility view all wretch.  It lags for several seconds when I try to scroll or press the page up/page down button.

Pagination, smaller data sets, and other usability suggestions will not work for this page.  Assume I absolutely have no choice but to display all this data at once... what are some things I can do to tweak it?

The data is being loaded via jQuery/Ajax and that seems to be at least in part suspect here, because when I created a test page to render the results directly it isn't *quite* as slow, but still not nearly as snappy as other browsers.

I've successfully used jQuery plugins such as SlickGrid to tackle similar problems in the past, but for reasons that would take a long time to explain they are not an option, even with the micro template rendering capabilities.  I'm mainly concerned with what tweaks I can make to improve performance without reworking the entire page or introducing third party solutions.

Is a simplified DOM going to make a big difference?  Or does IE not handle data brought in via JavaScript/Ajax well?

Comment: I strongly suspect (based on a lot of experience with big pages in IE) that it has more to do with IE's basic ability to handle a big DOM, and not much to do with the dynamically updated DOM.  One thing also that has a big effect is your CSS. If you've got lots of "container" CSS selectors, I've seen that slow down IE quite a lot (though that was IE6, and IE8 is a lot better).

Comment: Also, you have to consider whether IE (or any other web browser) was designed to handle 300 pages of data!

Comment: I don't have the URL anymore (sorry it's been a while). I think I remember reading something that IE6 (maybe 7 as well) would simply crash once so many rows in a table had been loaded and/or leaked memory.

If you have to have it load in a single page what do you think about doing something similar to how Google Reader works? Load up the first 50, or so, and then as the user scrolls down it would load the next 50, or so? This way you're not doing a ton of work all at once, but it still functions like you want...

Comment: I hope you're not using tables to display that "tabular" data.  If you are, make sure you set the "table-layout:fixed" CSS style.  Otherwise, the browser will have to wait until it downloads and lays out the entire page before it can calculate column widths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difficult to see without more details or an example... how are you building the content? There are quite a few little catches with building table content: in particular setting `innerHTML` directly on `<table>` doesn't work in IE, so jQuery's `html()` will probably be doing it a long, slow way round if that's what you're using.

But a general-purpose tip for anything with tables, especially larger ones: set the style `table-layout: fixed` on the `<table>` element, setting column `width` styles on either the first row of cells only, or on a set of `<col>`​s. (Columns without an explicit `width` will share the remaining width equally between them in a liquid layout situation.)

Since it does not depend on the quantity of content in each cell, `fixed` table layout is faster and much more predictable than the default `auto` table layout algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

use innerHTML and minimise js / dom interaction. Js isn't that slow in IE but the js/dom bridge is very slow. Also avoid to select elements in the html you are about to insert. If you do so, jQuery will have to walk through each element and test against the id or css attribute. This is very slow.

In itself inserting a few thousands elements in the DOM in IE is doable. but if you start doing some changes on this html, you may runs into severe perf issues.

Beyond that, your code is needed in order to tell how to make it faster. also a test page that can be profiled would be great.

FYI, the only performance profiling tool available for IE is dynatrace ajax version. Its free and an excellent quality software. Use it !

Answer (score 0):

I've found that when you're dynamically inserting large, complex content into an existing page, IE is much (much) faster at setting `innerHTML` than at programmatically creating dozens or hundreds of DOM nodes and inserting them, whether you're using a client-side library or not. If you render your HTML server-side and send it down as a string instead of sending JSON data and rendering client side, you're using more bandwidth, but your IE users will probably have a better experience.

IE's javascript performance is currently pretty terrible, so if you want to make your site faster in IE, minimizing large-scale DOM manipulation is a good start. It shouldn't be too difficult to make a simple test case for comparison, to see if such a change will benefit your particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for jQuery .find() in IE8.  If it's not carefully written, you might be causing IE8 to do some pretty ridiculous gymnastics.  Wish I knew more about why, etc etc but if you comment out your .find() in your jQuery and run it, even though your script is temporarily broken, you might see that the page is suddenly loading quickly.

Just a guess, but easy to try.

Answer (score 0):

```
   1. Avoid using script that going to make changes in DOM specially inside a loop.
        eg.

for ( var i = 0; i < rownodes.length; i++) {
  curRow = document.createElement("tr"); // this is a direct operation to DOM
  for(j=0 ;j <colLenth;j==){ 
     cell = document.createElement("td");
   }
}
// instead use..
var table = '<table>';
for ( var i = 0; i < rownodes.length; i++) {
   table = table + '<tr>'; // don't use DOM operation if not needed.
    for(j=0 ;j <colLenth;j==){   
      table = table + '<td> my text </td>';
    }
}
table = table + '</table>';// simple string operations will be much faster
('#myDiv').append($(table));// at the end you can add it to the DOM. 

[Building High Performance HTML Pages][1]

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Can also improve your rendering of table by improving it's presentation.
   by adding  colgroup by this the rendering of the table becomes fast(can see the difference when working with large tables) as browser engine doesn't have to look for individual col width's.

> ```
>  <table style="table-layout: fixed" width="600">
>     <colgroup>
>         <col width="100"><col width="300"><col width="200">
>     </colgroup>
>     <tr height="20">
>         <td>ss</td>
>         <td>ss</td>
>         <td>ss</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr></tr>
>    ....
>    ...
> </table>
> ```

```
see the below link for detailed discription
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533002(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: sorry for the earlier post the link was not working and the actual answer doesn't contained the code snippet.